# Need to make tiny mce editable based on dropdown selection

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

In a sharepoint webpart built on angular js I have used tiny mce editor. At first I show tiny mce editor with readonly mode. Later based on dropdown selection I need to change it to editable mode. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 tiny mce instances for same ng-model. One for readonly mode and another one for 
editable mode. Based on your selection show/hide the html 
element.

See below example

```
<div ng-show="showReadOnly">
   <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptionsReadOnly" ng-model="testModel" ></textarea>
</div>
<div ng-show="!showReadOnly">
   <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="testModel" ></textarea>
</div>
```

and in your controller add two tinymce options, one for readonly and another one for editable mode.

```
$scope.tinymceOptionsReadOnly = {           
    theme : 'advanced',
    readonly : 1
};

$scope.tinymceOptions = {           
    theme : 'advanced'
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working.